# Is there a name for the substitution of "the + singular noun" for a plural noun?

Tags: nouns, terminology, definite-articles, literary-device, rhetorical-devices

For instance, I might say, "Overcrowding is a major concern in **the classroom** today" rather than "Overcrowding is a major concern in **classrooms** today".
Is that substitution a literary device? 
The closest I can get is metonymy or synechdoche, which have similar functions but still don't match this specific kind of substitution.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's just a form of synechdoche. The phrase "the classroom" is not substituting for "classrooms" though, but "schools" (which have classrooms as their parts).

Comment: Ahhhh! Good point, that does make more sense.

Comment: It's still a good question. There might be a more specific name for a form that uses the specific structure "the X" to mean some larger thing that contains many Xs. [Pars pro toto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pars_pro_toto) is a more specific term for a part referring to a whole (while synechdoche refers to both that and the reverse), but it's not limited to the "the X" form.

Comment: @Blckknght: It can be a form of synecdoche, but not all usages fall into that category. It certainly doesn't in literal sentences like "The camel is a beast of burden that can withstand heat and drought" or "The sea is rough today." (Contrasting with "Camels are beasts of burden" and "We are facing heavy seas today.")

Comment: It's called the '**definite generic**'. [Professor Lawler's thesis](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/dissertation/IV-GenericNPs.pdf) is probably still the go-to treatment of generic usages. "Overcrowding is a major concern in classrooms today" is still a generic usage (the _plural generic_); it represents an unspecified (but substantial) subset of all classrooms (as does 'the classroom') rather than truly specified classrooms.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth for those who might wish to dig in (concerning Japanese) (https://www.euroslajournal.org/articles/10.22599/jesla.46/. "Definite generic vs. definite unique in L2 acquisition". "Definite generic can refer to more than one individual when it is accompanied by a predicate like be extinct: one picture of a single dodo bird AND a picture of a set of dodo birds can refer to the entire species of dodo bird. Definite unique is when the definite article refers to one individual"

Comment: @ShpielMeister Therefore "The camel is a beast of burden that can..." is Definite generic, whilst "The camel, in the picture, is a beast of burden that can..." is definite unique????

Comment: Here's [the Cliff's on generic NPs](http://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/000001.html). Generic verb phrases (like _Bill drives a Chevy_ and _That dog bites_) are a different story entirely.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any difference in meaning between the definite, the indefinite, and the zero article when we make generic nouns?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/251149/is-there-any-difference-in-meaning-between-the-definite-the-indefinite-and-the)

Answer (score 0):

It's called "**definite generic**" (as opposed to "*definite unique*") as discussed in "[Definite generic vs. definite unique in L2 acquisition](https://www.euroslajournal.org/articles/10.22599/jesla.46/)" by Neal Snape in the *Journal of the European Second Language Association* (JESLA).

Answer (score 0):

> For instance, I might say, "Overcrowding is a major concern in the classroom today" rather than "Overcrowding is a major concern in classrooms today". Is that substitution a literary device?

No. The substitution is not primarily a literary device. The sentences carry similar information but are expressed in different ways.

> in **the** classroom today

**The** is an anaphoric that assumes that the speaker and listener are already aware of the particular classroom that is being discussed.

As it happens the poster, Blackknight, above explains this specific instance (so I don't have to):

> I'm pretty sure that's just a form of synechdoche. The phrase "the classroom" is not substituting for "classrooms" though, but "schools" (which have classrooms as their parts).

It should **not** be assumed that all such **the noun -> nouns** are synecdoche.

> in classroom**s** today

This is the plural of *in **a** classroom today*. which means *in an example of a classroom.* (The indefinite article implies "one [typical] example from many.")

Thus = in example**s** of classrooms.