# "The" and "A" at the beginning of explanation

Tags: articles

I am little bit confused about the usage of the article "The" and "A". For example, following pages start their description from "A".

#### Starts with "A"

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laptop

> A laptop (also laptop computer), often called a notebook, is ...

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dictionary

> A dictionary is a listing of words in one or more specific languages ...

On the other hand, following pages start with "The".

#### Starts with "The"

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron

> The electron is a subatomic particle, symbol ...

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipe_organ

> The pipe organ is a musical instrument that ...

Each word is countable noun and they do not have any context because all of them are first line of the explanation.

Even the purpose looks same for me.
I mean, all of them explain abstract nature of the noun.

What is the difference "The" and "A" in such the case ?

Comment: This is a great question.  As a native speaker, I find that the sentences you've quoted become less idiomatic if you replace "A" with "The" or vice versa, but I cannot explain why.

Comment: A/an noun = an example (from among many) of a noun. "A dog is a good pet." ++ **The** is a demonstrative adjective related to **that/those**. **The** noun = the noun that we know or is described.  e.g. **"The cat *on the table*"** - *on the table* describes the cat. "The noun" = the noun with which everyone is familiar, "**The** moon is bright." ++ If you approach a stranger and say "The dog is big." He will think you are mad, and say, "Which dog?" If you say " "A dog is a good pet.", he will probably agree.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any difference in meaning between the definite, the indefinite, and the zero article when we make generic nouns?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/251149/is-there-any-difference-in-meaning-between-the-definite-the-indefinite-and-the) Choice may be influenced by how prestigious the referent is deemed to be (the tiger is a majestic animal, the ...' / 'an ant is a social insect ...'.

Comment: "The" is used when referring to a quintessential/ideal entity, in addition to it's use for a specific entity.